# Which permissions are required to succesfully execute boost::filesystem::last_write_time?

Tags: c++, linux, file-permissions, boost-filesystem

This simple code:

```
std::time_t tm = boost::filesystem::last_write_time( filename );
boost::filesystem::last_write_time( directory, tm );
```

throws an "Operation not permitted" exception if `directory` is a path owned by a user other than the one executing the code.

I'm a bit confused by this as I'm dealing with directories having `777` or `rwxrwxrwx` permissions, and I can easily change their modification times by using `touch` in a shell.

Am I missing something? Is Boost asking for more permissions than it needs? Is there a way I can fix this?

Here's the relevant code in Boost:

```
handle_wrapper hw(
  create_file( ph.c_str(), FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES,
    FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0 ) );
if ( hw.handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
  return error_code( ::GetLastError(), system_category );
return error_code( ::SetFileTime( hw.handle, 0, 0, &last_write_time ) != 0
  ? 0 : ::GetLastError(), system_category );
```

Comment: `GetLastError` and `SetFileTime` are Windows functions. Is this on Linux, Cygwin, or something else?

Comment: linux, as per tag. I noticed that as well, I just thought Boost reimplements them. Or maybe I got the wrong file. Point is, it does work, except for that quirky permission thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet `touch -r file directory` also fails. This would use the timestamp of `file` instead of current time.

I can't find explicit documentation on the behavior, but the underlying call (`utime` or `utimensat`) fails if you both set an explicit time and do not own the file you are touching.

```
$ touch foo
$ touch bar
$ sudo chmod a+rw bar
$ sudo chown root.root bar
$ touch bar
# success
$ touch -r foo bar
touch: setting times of `bar': Operation not permitted
```

It makes sense if you think about it. If you have write permission to the file/directory, then you could manually edit to change the modification time to now. But setting the modification time to some other time requires ownership.

Comment: Ah yes, this was the missing piece of the puzzle. Thanks!